# OSX: Maya's Python instance replaces `python`

Tags: python, macos, maya

On my OSX 10.9.2 I have Maya 2014 Student Version installed, which ships with Python 2.7.3. The problem is that now whenever I run `python` in bash, Maya's Python interpreter is always launched, which is located at:

`/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

I have verified what `python` exactly points to by using `which` and `ls -l`:

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  7 May 24 12:21 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python -> python2

$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  9 May 24 12:21 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 -> python2.7

$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  25624 Nov 10  2013 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Which means that `python` eventually points to `python2.7`, the latter being an executable instead of a link. But when I run `python` and suspend the interpreter using `Ctrl` + `Z` and list the processes using `ps`, I see:

```
67937 ttys001    0:00.03 /Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Any ideas on how this could happen? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe look at aliases? What does `alias` print?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Thanks, but nope, `alias` prints nothing...

Comment: Sometimes installers mess with your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Is there anything suspicious there?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi I checked that as well - I only have `.profile` in which I found `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}" export PATH`. After commenting this out `which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python`, which in turns points to `../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`.

Comment: Try `typeset -f` to see if maybe a `python` bash function is defined?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Good thought - but `typeset -f | grep python` returns nothing either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is the following lines in `.profile` that overrides the expected `python` executable path:

```
MAYA_LOCATION=/Applications/Autodesk/maya2014/Maya.app/Contents
export MAYA_LOCATION
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH:$MAYA_LOCATION/Frameworks
export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
```

After commenting these lines out, I managed to have `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` running.

According to Mac Developer Library (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html), `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` overrides the directories in which frameworks will be searched for. But it is weird that even if `/usr/local/bin/python` points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`, `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` is still able to override it.

Practically solved, but still don't know how `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` affects `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`.